# Abstract base class design in Go vs C++

Tags: go, virtual, composition

I am still learning the Go way of doing things, coming from a C++ background. I am looking for feedback contrasting OOP inheritance to interface composition.

I have a design situation in a Go program where, if I was implementing in C++, I would solve with an abstract base class.

Suppose I need a base class, which has many implementors. The base class has shared methods that do work on abstract data items.  Different Worker implementations provide CRUD operations on different item types, but workers all use the shared methods of the base class for general work.

In C++ I might do it this way

```
class IItem
{
    // virtual methods
};

class IWorker
{
public:
    // one of many virtual functions that deal with IItem CRUD
    virtual IItem* createItem() = 0; 

    // concrete method that works on interfaces
    void doWork()
    {
        IItem* item = createItem();
        // do stuff with an IItem*
    }

};


class Toy : public IItem
{

};

// one of many kinds of workers
class ElfWorker : public IWorker
{
public:

    ElfWorker()
    {
        // constructor implicitly calls IWorker()
    }

    IItem* createItem() override
    {
        return new Toy;
    }
};
```

In Go you don't have abstract virtual methods such as IWorker::createItem().  Concrete classes need to supply the base with an interface or function that do the right thing.

So I think it is the case that the Go code the ew.ItemCRUD interface has to be explicitly set with a pointer to an ElfWorker.

The elf knows how to createItem(), which in his case happens to be Toy object. Other workers would implement their own ItemCRUD for their data objects.

```
type Item interface {                         
    // various methods                                                                                
}
type ItemCRUD interface {                                                                             
    create() Item                                                                                     
    // other CRUD                                                                                     
}                                                                                                     

type Worker struct {
    ItemCRUD  // embedded interface                                                                                        
}                                                                                                     
func (w *Worker) doWork() {
    item := w.create()                                                                                
    // do stuff with item                                                                          
}

type Toy struct {
}

type ElfWorker struct {                                                                               
    Worker // embedded                                                                                
    // ..
}       

func NewElfWorker() *ElfWorker {                                                                      
    ew := &ElfWorker{}                                                                                
    ew.ItemCRUD = ew // <-- #### set Worker ItemCRUD  explicitly ####                                                  
    return ew                                                                                         
}                                                                                                     

func (ew *ElfWorker) createItem() Item {
    return &Toy{}                                                                                     
}
// more ElfWorker Item CRUD
func bigFunction(w *Worker) {                                                                     
    // ...                                                                                            
    w.doWork()  
   // ..                                                                                       
}
```

So the part that I am wrestling a bit with is explicit setting.  Seems like the "Go way" of composition does require this **explicit** step if I want the base Worker class to provide shared methods on Items.

Thoughts?

Comment: Drawing parallels between C++ and any other language can prove to be counter-productive.

Comment: first derivative to @Ron’s comment: Applying patterns found in other programming languages to Go can prove counter-productive.

Answer (score 0):

Beeing new to go myself, this answer is not backed by years of go experience :-)

I don't know, if the way you tackle this is the correct approach. 
go allows interfaces to be implemented without explicit declaration. If you have elves, and you need them to do `ItemCRUD` methods, just implement them.

The method set will then match the interface and you can use the elf as a `ItemCRUD` where required.

To supply any elf object with a default `ItemCRUD` Implementation, you should implement an adapter for the `ItemCRUD` and compose the adapter with your abstract elf. The abstract methods could have a default implementation as `log.Fatal("not implemented")`

The concrete elves shadow the adapter's methods, this answers your question: It is not required to insert the object during creation.

Yet, since go has no generics, it may not be the right approach to have an `ItemCRUD`.

Answer (score 0):

Im not entirely clear what the plan is with the above code and without understanding that its hard to suggest specific solutions, what is clear is you are very much coming to the party with an established OOP mindset (I did too) which is rarely helpful in finding the best solution in golang.

In Golang I wouldnt usually embed an interface in an implementation, interfaces are satisfied implicitly in Golang which allows for a nice separation of expectation and implementation which should generally be respected. 
A reciever method should expect an interface, the implementation passed at runtime should just satisfy the signature of that interface implicitly.

So perhaps my doWork method needs to be able to createItems then it would be the doWork method that would accept any implementation of ItemCRUD which it could call to create an item. But this is me guessing at what you really want to do here, I suspect if you just separate implementation from interface you will probably answer your own question.